# bialgebra cohomology

Tags: reference-request, homological-algebra

It seems that the Gerstenhaber-Schack (bi)complex of an associative bialgebra carries a homotopy e_3-algebra structure and a degree 2 Lie algebra bracket, up to homotopy. Does anyone know about a reference where these structures have been explicitly shown?

Comment: When you say 'it seems...' do you mean you've read it somewhere?

Comment: It seems that there's a sketch of the structure in:
Hopf algebras, tetramodules, and n-fold monoidal categories
Boris Shoikhet
http://arxiv.org/pdf/0907.3335v2.pdf

Comment: This has been partially written up by the same author in: http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1938

Answer (score 2):

It's done in Ginot-Yalin *Deformation theory of bialgebras, higher Hochschild cohomology and formality* ([arXiv:1606.01504](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.01504)

More precisely, my undertsanding is that what's true by abstract non-sense is that under some (co)nilpotency condition there's an equivalence between $E_2$-algebras and (dg-)bialgebras, and that the deformation complex of an $E_2$-algebra is $E_3$. What is done in that paper apart from carefully writing this up, is identifying this with the standard GS complex explaining and precisely in what way t controls deformations of bialgebra in this setting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about e3, but the Lie up to homotopy is in "Intrinsic brackets and the $L_{\infty}$-deformation theory of bialgebras" by Martin Markl, https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0411456.